# Cluster analysis after factor analysis: What distance measure to use?

Tags: factor-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I use factor analysis on a set of 15 survey questions (likert scales).
Using the *predict* command (in stata) I make 5 factors.

Subsequently, I want to use cluster analysis to see if there are "groups" of people with similar scores on the factors.

I find it hard to know which distance measure to use (e.g. singlelinkage, wards, correlation based measures).

My question is: What distance measure should I use on my data?